# reading a file outside a function to iterate through

Tags: python, function, loops

I have created a function, that I want to run over an entire file, but I am having some trouble. I am only getting output from the last line of the file.

I have two different input files, and the idea is to take the lines from one file and collecting certain terms, adding them to a dictionary, and then searching the second file for the corresponding lines and printing the output. I know the problem is most likely the placement of my call for the function.

The matrix file looks like this

```
        Sp_ds   Sp_hs   Sp_log  Sp_plat 
c3833_g1_i2     4.00    0.07    16.84   26.37 
c4832_g1_i1     24.55   116.87  220.53  28.82 
c5161_g1_i1     107.49  89.39   26.95   698.97 
c4399_g1_i2     27.91   72.57   5.56    36.58 
c5916_g1_i1     82.57   19.03   48.55   258.22
```

The Blast file looks like this

```
c0_g1_i1|m.1    gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO      100.00  372     0       0       1       372     1       372     0.0       754 
c1000_g1_i1|m.799       gi|48474761|sp|O94288.1|NOC3_SCHPO      100.00  747     0       0       5       751     1       747     0.0      1506 
c1001_g1_i1|m.800       gi|259016383|sp|O42919.3|RT26A_SCHPO    100.00  268     0       0       1       268     1       268     0.0       557 
c1002_g1_i1|m.801       gi|1723464|sp|Q10302.1|YD49_SCHPO       100.00  646     0       0       1       646     1       646     0.0      1310 
c1003_g1_i1|m.803       gi|74631197|sp|Q6BDR8.1|NSE4_SCHPO      100.00  246     0       0       1       246     1       246     1e-179    502 
c1004_g1_i1|m.804       gi|74676184|sp|O94325.1|PEX5_SCHPO      100.00  598     0       0       1       598     1       598     0.0      1227 
c1005_g1_i1|m.805       gi|9910811|sp|O42832.2|SPB1_SCHPO       100.00  802     0       0       1       802     1       802     0.0      1644 
c1006_g1_i1|m.806       gi|74627042|sp|O94631.1|MRM1_SCHPO      100.00  255     0       0       1       255     47      301     0.0       525 
c1007_g1_i1|m.807       gi|20137702|sp|O74370.1|ISY1_SCHPO      100.00  201     0       0       1       201     1       201     4e-146    412
```

The program that I have gotten so far is this

```
def parse_blast(blast_line="NA"):
    transcript = blast_line[0][0]
    swissProt = blast_line[1][3]
    return(transcript, swissProt)

blast = open("/scratch/RNASeq/blastp.outfmt6")
for line in blast:
      line= [item.split('|') for item in line.split()]
      (transcript, swissProt) = parse_blast(blast_line = line)


transcript_to_protein = {}
transcript_to_protein[transcript] = swissProt
if transcript in transcript_to_protein:
        protein = transcript_to_protein.get(transcript)

matrix = open("/scratch/RNASeq/diffExpr.P1e-3_C2.matrix")
for line in matrix:
      matrixFields = line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
      transcript = matrixFields[0]
      Sp_ds = matrixFields[1]
      Sp_hs = matrixFields[2]
      Sp_log = matrixFields[3]
      Sp_plat = matrixFields[4]

tab = "\t"
fields = (protein,Sp_ds,Sp_hs,Sp_log,Sp_plat)
out = open("parsed_blast.txt","w")
out.write(tab.join(fields))
matrix.close()
blast.close()
out.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope problem, as your indentation is not correct.

```
for line in blast:
  line= [item.split('|') for item in line.split()]
  (transcript, swissProt) = parse_blast(blast_line = line)
```

So you keep looping till the last line without saving the values you get.
I think you should change your indentation to this

```
transcript_to_protein = {} # 1. declare the dictionary

for line in blast:
      line= [item.split('|') for item in line.split()]
      (transcript, swissProt) = parse_blast(blast_line = line)
      transcript_to_protein[transcript] = swissProt # 2. Add the data to the dictionary
```

This will solve the problem of your first file.But not your second as you don't use the dictionary inside the loop.

So you have to move these lines inside the second loop

```
if transcript in transcript_to_protein:
    protein = transcript_to_protein.get(transcript)
```

I think you got the idea. I will leave the rest for you to do, there a few lines that needs to be moved before the loops and one or two inside the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
for line in blast:
      line= [item.split('|') for item in line.split()]
      (transcript, swissProt) = parse_blast(blast_line = line)
```

Reads all the lines, but after it is finished (transcript, swissProt) will only have the value from the last line.

Same for:

```
for line in matrix:
      matrixFields = line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
      transcript = matrixFields[0]
      Sp_ds = matrixFields[1]
      Sp_hs = matrixFields[2]
      Sp_log = matrixFields[3]
      Sp_plat = matrixFields[4]
```

You need to put the rest of your line processing inside your loops.